# Using the Squeeze Theorem on $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$$

I'm trying to evaluate this limit using Squeeze Theorem. However, looking at the graph I know it approaches $1$, but I am getting $0$ using the Squeeze Theorem.

$$-\frac{1}{x^2} < \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2} < \frac{1}{x^2}$$

when I sub in $0$ it's just $0$. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Wait, it's not zero! The upper and lower bounds are indeterminate. So I can't use squeeze theorem, correct?

Comment: $1/x^2\to +\infty$

Comment: You can only use squeeze theorem when upper and lower bound limits exist and are equal.

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 5):

The lower and upper bounds you write are right, but unfortunately the lower bound has limit $-\infty$ and the upper bound has limit $\infty$, so they can't be used to determine the given limit.

If you want to apply squeezing, you can prove geometrically that
$$
\cos^2x<\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}<\frac{1}{\cos^2x}
$$
which is basically the usual proof that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$

Answer (score 3):

The function is even, we assume $0<x<1$.

By MVT,
$$\sin(x)=x\cos(c)$$ with $0<c<x$.

thus

$$\cos^2(x)<\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}=\cos^2(c)<1$$

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, the upper and lower bounds are indeterminate. Therefore, you cannot determine the limit that way. Instead, you can refer to the following [well-known limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

If you want to use the Squeeze Theorem, you can refer to the geometric proof of the limit above. (Then, you can apply the geometric proof here and reach a conclusion by the Squeeze Theorem.)